# What is the solr literal function for?

Tags: solr

I've been playing around with the [literal query function](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#literal) and given it's documentation, I can't seem to figure out what it *actually* does. Can anyone elaborate on what the solr literal function is for?

Answer (score 0):

Is't it just giving you the option to ie. add a value to the document or use it in the other function?

Comment: I thought that might be it too, but when I played around with it, it does not seem to be the case. I could be wrong, if you have documentation that sheds light on it, or a good example?

Comment: I looked up docs and the one I've found are pretty vague. http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#literal